# FALSE changed to "false" while using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I'm reading a text file using `pd.read_csv`. There are columns that has "FALSE" and "TRUE" as cell values. When I read the files, the "FALSE"  turns to "False' and "TRUE" is changed as "true". The script is given below.

```
input_file_1 = pd.read_csv(input_file,delimiter="\t")
```

I want all those values in upper case. I don't want to force fit uppercase for those specific column as I'm trying to generalize the script for any file.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `False` or `false`? `True` or `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are interpreted as booleans, to save them as upper case strings you can specify the type of those columns

```
pd.read_csv(input_file, delimiter="\t", dtype={'column1': str, 'column2': str})
```

or treat all the columns as strings

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\GuySaban\Desktop\test.csv', delimiter=",", dtype=str)
```

Comment: Thank you... But as I said, i don't want to specifically call out the column names as they may differ for each file...  I actually want all the columns to be in string format... Is there a way to read all the columns as strings? so that I don't have to specify the column names?

Comment: I added "dtype=str" and this works fine now... Thank you

Comment: @Suganya yes, with `dtype=str`